# Cloud storage where others can add/modify but not delete?

Tags: git, cloud-storage, version-control, statistics

I have a large collection of files to share for everyone, and I'm looking for a cloud service that matches all or some of these needs (sorted by importance):

- Allow others to upload, download files, create folders and move files between folders, but restrict them from delete files
- Be recoverable if something goes wrong (revert deletions)
- Visitors can view without downloading (mostly PDF)
- Have stat, or can integrate with Google Analytics
- Free for a couple GB (at least 3 GB)
- Visitors can have a synced copy in their hard drive

So far I'm using Google Drive, but the edit mode allow others to delete the files as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) is an open-source alternative to google drive. The software is free but it is self-hosted. Registered users can also sync documents shared with them.

✔️ Allow visitors to upload, download files, create folders and move files between folders, but restrict them from delete files
✔️ Be recoverable if something goes wrong
✔️ Visitors can view without downloading
❌ Have stat, or can integrate with Google Analytics
✔️ Free for a couple GB: you can choose [free providers listed on their website](https://nextcloud.com/signup/), or your own host by your wish
✔️ Visitors can have a synced copy in their hard drive

Comment: Have stat: to a degree, see e.g. the Nextcloud app [Usage Report](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/user_usage_report) or the Activity page.

Answer (score 0):

One limited option is to keep using Google Drive, set the whole folder as "can view" privilege, and create a folder in "can edit" privilege.

Many good discussion and other options can be found here: [Cloud services that can open for everyone to edit, but not delete files : opendirectories](https://www.reddit.com/r/opendirectories/comments/clk77s/cloud_services_that_can_open_for_everyone_to_edit/)